# PIGRRL Gamepad - OS Raspberry Pi in loop

Tags: operating-system, gamepad, adafruit

I am new here but I hope you can help me to find a solution to my problem.
I have four PIGRRL Kit from Adafruit and I need to install in it Raspbian (Operating System), the PiTFT and the gamepad as shown here (https://learn.adafruit.com/pigrrl-2/software).

But, when I try to install the gamepad, the OS goes in loop and the only way to exit it is to restart everything. I have checked if there were some problems with the soldering, but the voltage machine is not showing me any problem of the kind. The problem is just on the gamepad, because at the PITFT installation step everything goes fine and works.
But when I install the gamepad it goes in loop.
I used these commands:

```
cd
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adafruit/Raspberry-Pi-Installer-Scripts/master/retrogame.sh    
sudo bash retrogame.sh
```

And then I follow the instructions for PIGRRL 2.0. But when I reboot, the OS loops.
Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried retrogame, but I'm trying to use PiTFT 28 capacitive.

What I can say is that have some troubles with the display :).

In the first time I follow exactly they procedure and made my software work perfectly. But at some point in time it started to reboot after starting the software.

So I tried to start all over again, but this time I used Diet Pi and follow an alternative solution. I follow the procedure on this page: http://www.0xf8.org/2016/01/complete-rotation-support-for-the-adafruit-pitft-2-8-capacitive-touchscreen-display/

The display works, but:
1. If I use other console font, it starting immediately the font is going active. 
2. The mouse don't work so well, it seems to start all the time in the left corner. So I didn't manage this part. :).

Maybe my answer can be useful in the combination of your experience.

Bafta

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem for me was solved by charging the batteries. Basically, when it first reboots the OS needs more energy and with no charged batteries it went in loop.

All the best!